Why is the backend using only Stripe connected account ID instead of handling account numbers?
I’m working on an integration with Stripe, specifically handling fund transfers to connected accounts. In my current API, when creating a connected account using stripe.Account.create(), I don’t see any place where the user’s bank account number is requested. Instead, only the connected account ID is returned and used for all further operations.
Here are my questions:
Where does Stripe ask for the account number?
    I noticed that during the connected account creation, only basic details like email, country, and business type are required. Does Stripe automatically handle account numbers later in the onboarding process or in a different API call?

Why doesn’t the backend handle account numbers directly?
    In my API, I only store the connected account ID, but not the actual bank account details. Is this the recommended practice, and if so, why?

How does the frontend and backend interact for bank account details?
    If the frontend needs to collect bank account details from the user (like routing and account number), should this data be sent to the backend or directly to Stripe? What is the best approach to securely handle this ?

I’ve implemented an API where I use the Stripe connected account ID to handle fund transfers. Here’s the process I followed:
I create a connected account using stripe.Account.create(), which returns a connected account ID.
I store and use this connected account ID for future transactions, like transferring funds to the user’s account using stripe.Transfer.create().

I expected Stripe to automatically handle the user's bank account number during the connected account creation or later in the onboarding process. I thought the connected account ID would implicitly include or be linked to the user's bank account details, such as the routing and account number, without requiring me to handle those details directly in my backend.

The recommendation is that you use Stripe's hosted onboarding UI after account creation to collect the necessary verification/identity information from users. The hosted onboarding also supports collecting external bank account info for payouts.
